# Entity operations and redirect destination (using EntityListBuilder)

Tags: entities, 8, redirection

I have an entity collection page that's built with my own subclass of `EntityListBuilder`. My problem is that the operations links do not set a redirect destination, so after clicking e.g. on an edit link, it is hard for the user to find their way back to the listing.

Redirect destinations work fine with simple links. But I couldn't figure out an easy way how to tell `EntityBuilder::buildOperations()` to include the `destination` query string. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildOperations` is to change the render array for the link wrapper.

The method you are looking for is `getOperations`. Just pick the operation you want and add the query string to the url.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Got too many other projects right now. Will soon try out your suggestion, which makes sense to me.